# want to add a new flyway in between existing schema version

Tags: flyway

I have version v1, v2 in schema_version table.
I want to add version v1.1 in between.
How can i do it using cmd's with out manually dropping v2 and running flyway migrate once again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run with outOfOrder turned on; see the [migrate docs](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/commandline/migrate).

> ```
> Option: outOfOrder
> Required: No
> Default: false
> Description: Allows migrations to be run "out of order". 
> If you already have versions 1 and 3 applied, and now a version 2 is found, it will be applied too instead of being ignored.
> ```

If you're running via the command line then do the following:

1. Add new migration as `V1.1__description.sql` or similar
2. Run flyway again with `-outOfOrder true`